# Swift: Filter a Dictionary with Array as Value

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

I'm new to Swift programming. For my particular project, I'm trying to filter a dictionary with some user input, and the dictionary's value consists of an array.

Here is some sample code, and what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var dictionary = ["a": ["aberration", "abc"], "b" : ["babel", "bereft"]]

var filteredDictionary = [String: [String]]()

var searchText = "aberration"

//getting the first letter of string
var firstLetter = searchText[searchText.startIndex]
```

With this particular searchText, I'm trying to get:

```
filteredDictionary = ["a": ["aberration"]]
```

Edit: I want the dictionary to return with the first letter as its key, and the values with what searchText matches up with. Sorry if it I wasn't clear.

Here is some code I have tried, but obviously, I can't get it to work:

```
filteredDictionary = dictionary.filter{$0.key == firstLetter && for element in $0.value { element.hasPrefix(searchText) }}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you exactly you trying to filter?

Comment: I updated the question. I want to return a dictionary with the letter as its key, and the matching searchText as an array as its value.

Comment: The part you really need to clarify is what values in the array should be returned. It seems you want any word that has a prefix matching `searchText` but you don't make that clear (it's implied based on your code though). What if `searchText` is `abe`? Do you still want just `aberration`? What if `searchText is `ab`? Do you want both `aberration` and `abc` since both start with `ab`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that maps the values based on the search and then filters out the empty results.

```
var dictionary = ["a": ["aberration", "abc"], "b" : ["babel", "bereft"]]
var searchText = "aberration"
let filteredDictionary = dictionary.mapValues { $0.filter { $0.hasPrefix(searchText) } }.filter { !$0.value.isEmpty }
print(filteredDictionary)
```

Output:

> ["a": ["aberration"]]

Comment: As a followup question, how can you filter it so that it does not filter out the empty results, such that filteredDictionary keeps its keys?

["a": ["aberration"], "b" : [], "c" : [], "d" : []  ] etc.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it by getting rid of the last segment like so:
filteredDictionary = dictionary.mapValues { $0.filter { $0.hasPrefix(searchText) } }

Comment: Correct, just drop the `.filter { !$0.value.isEmpty }` if you want to keep the empty keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
let firstLetter = String(searchText[searchText.startIndex])
let filteredDictionary = dictionary
    .reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { (result, object) in
        if object.key == firstLetter {
            let array = object.value.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchText) })
            if array.count > 0 {
                result[object.key] = array
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ["a": ["aberration"]]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var dictionary = ["a": ["aberration", "abc"], "b" : ["babel", "bereft"]]
    var searchText = "aberration"
    var filteredDictionary = dictionary.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in
            return (value as! [String]).contains(searchText)
        }.mapValues { (values) -> [String] in
            return [searchText]
        }
    print(filteredDictionary)
```

You can use a combination of **`filter`** and **`map`** to achieve the desired result.

**Output:**

```
["a": ["aberration"]]
```

Comment: The values returned by this are not filtered as indicated in the question.

Comment: This still isn't correct since the search text needs to be a prefix and can match more than one value in each array.

Comment: It isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: It's implied based on the use of `hasPrefix` in the question's code.

Comment: Requirements must be specified clearly in the question. Just adding the code isn't enough.